# Training loss doesn't match validation loss when X_train = X_test

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am running:

```python
D.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=12,validation_data=(X_train,y_train))
```

But I get outputs like:

```python
Train on 61936 samples, validate on 61936 samples
Epoch 1/12
61936/61936 [==============================] - 10s 166us/step - loss: 0.0021 - val_loss: 1.5650e-04
Epoch 2/12
61936/61936 [==============================] - 10s 165us/step - loss: 0.0014 - val_loss: 6.6482e-04
...
Epoch 10/12
61936/61936 [==============================] - 11s 170us/step - loss: 0.0104 - val_loss: 9.6666e-05
```

Comment: More context would help

Comment: I'm training on simple b/w images with a fully connected NN 22 layers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

known issue

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/605

> The other reason that the results are different is because the model
>   is being trained while the "loss" is being computed, whereas the model
>   is fixed while "val_loss" is being computed. Since the model is
>   training, "loss" is typically going to be larger than the true
>   training set loss at the end of the epoch. I.e. "loss" is the average
>   loss during the epoch, and "val_loss" is the average loss after the
>   end of the epoch. Since the model changes during the epoch, the loss
>   changes.

Answer (score 3):

These will never match. Validation loss is computed on the whole dataset at once (with weights fixed), with training loss is the **average** of loss across batches (weights change after every batch). If you want the real loss on the training set, you should run `model.evaluate(X_train)`

Comment: So if the performance was getting better with epochs, would I expect to see training loss after 5 epochs will be smaller than validation loss after first epoch?

Comment: @user7867665 No, there are no guarantees of any kind on loss values.